# R Shiny shinyjqui not working for dynamic server UI

Tags: jquery, r, shiny

I am using the **shinyjqui** package and believe following code should create draggable UI/plots. However after using the **Add UI** button to add 2+ more plots, the returned objects are not draggable. I can however get it to work when I make the entire output **main_output** draggable, but this is not what I want.

Any suggestions?

Minimal example below:

```
library(shinyjqui)

ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        verticalLayout(
            uiOutput('main_output')
        )
    )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$main_output <- renderUI({
        uiOutput('moduel_box')
    })

    render_moduels <- reactiveValues(input_types = NULL)

    observeEvent(input$add, {

        plot_type <- as.character(input$select)

        input_types <- render_moduels$input_types

        render_types <- unique(c(input_types, plot_type))

        render_moduels$input_types <- render_types

        output_types <<- c(render_moduels$input_types, 'moduel_box')

        output$main_output <- renderUI({

            lapply(output_types, uiOutput)

        })

        jqui_draggabled(paste0('#', output_types, sep=',', collapse = ''))

    })

    # jqui_draggable('#main_output') #This works though?

    output$moduel_box <- renderUI({
        box(width = '100%', 
            actionButton("add", "Add UI"),
            selectInput('select', 'please select', choices = c('histogram', 'line_plot'))
        )
    })
    output$histogram <- renderUI({

        box(
            renderPlot(hist(iris$Sepal.Length,30)),
            actionButton('rmv', 'remove')
        )
    })

    output$line_plot <- renderUI({

        box(
            renderPlot(plot(iris$Sepal.Length, type='l')),
            actionButton('rmv', 'remove')
        )
    })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This what I get when running your code: `Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5529
Warning: Error in box: plot.new has not been called yet
  [No stack trace available]`.

Comment: I've just run the code myself and it worked fine?

Answer (score 1):

The selector for multiple elements should be in the format of `"#id1,#id2"` but not `"#id1,#id2,"`, so the expression of `jqui_draggabled` should be changed to `jqui_draggabled(paste0('#', output_types, sep='', collapse = ','))`.

To make the logic of dynamic UI clearer, I would suggest to use `shiny::insertUI` here:

```
observeEvent(input$add, {    
  plot_type <- as.character(input$select)    
  input_types <- render_moduels$input_types    
  if (plot_type %in% input_types) return()
  render_moduels$input_types <- c(input_types, plot_type)
  insertUI(
    selector = "#moduel_box",
    where    = "beforeBegin",
    ui       = jqui_draggabled(uiOutput(plot_type))
  )
})
```

And, btw, the `box` function is from `shinydashboard` package, you should load it in the beginning.